# Use Entity Framework's StructuralTypeConfiguration.Ignore() to Ignore all properties but specified set

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In EF CodeFirst Fluent API I can write something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Ignore(e => e.Property1);
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Ignore(e => e.Property2);
```

How to ignore all properites but a tiny set, like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .IgnoreAllBut(e => e.ID, e => e.Important);
```

Is it possible to write extension method like this `IgnoreAllBut`?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible using Reflection and calls to Ignore. It's not something that the fluent API supports out of the box. Do you need more detailed help on how to do it with Reflection?

Comment: I would appreciate help because when I construct property expression with `Expression.Property()` and try to use it in `Ignore()` I get: `The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Added this expression problem as new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621736/how-to-convert-propertyinfo-to-property-expression-and-use-it-to-invoke-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is draft, but works:

```
public static void IgnoreAllBut<TStructuralType>(
    this StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType> configuration,
    params Expression<Func<TStructuralType, object>>[] includes)
    where TStructuralType : class
{
    var includeMembers = ConvertExpressionsToMembers(includes);
    var type = typeof(TStructuralType);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    var typeParameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var configurationType = configuration.GetType();
    var ignoreMethod = configurationType.GetMethod("Ignore");
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (!includeMembers.Any(member => member.Name == property.Name))
        {
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(typeParameter, property);
            var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, typeParameter);
            var genericIgnoreMethod = ignoreMethod.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
            var parameters = new object[] { lambdaExpression };
            genericIgnoreMethod.Invoke(configuration, parameters);
        }
    }
}

private static List<MemberInfo> ConvertExpressionsToMembers<TStructuralType>(
    Expression<Func<TStructuralType, object>>[] expressions)
{
    var members = new List<MemberInfo>();
    foreach (var lambda in expressions)
    {
        var expression = lambda.Body;
        var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            var unaryExpression = expression as UnaryExpression;
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        members.Add(memberExpression.Member);
    }
    return members;
}
```

Thanks to DarkGray for code in linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621736/how-to-convert-propertyinfo-to-property-expression-and-use-it-to-invoke-generic).