# How to convert PropertyInfo to property expression and use it to invoke generic method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reflection

How to convert [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) to property expression which can be used to invoke [`StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Ignore<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TStructuralType, TProperty>> propertyExpression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671225%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method?

I tried to use [`Expression.Property()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348662.aspx) to construct expression but I am getting following error when I use this expression as `propertyExpression` parameter:

`The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

This error probably refers to `TProperty` type parameter which I don't know how to specify having only `PropertyInfo`.

I am doing this in relation to: [Use Entity Framework's StructuralTypeConfiguration.Ignore() to Ignore all properties but specified set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585263/use-entity-frameworks-structuraltypeconfiguration-ignore-to-ignore-all-proper).

**UPDATE**

Code which is not working:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(Foo).GetProperties()[0];
var expression = Expression.Default(typeof(Foo));
var expressionProperty = Expression.Property(expression, propertyInfo);
Ignore(expressionProperty);
```

Comment: You should show your code which isn't working...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var entityType = propertyInfo.DeclaringType;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);

structureConfiguration.GetType()
   .GetMethod("Ignore")
   .MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType)
   .Invoke(structureConfiguration, new[]{lambda});
```

Comment: Tried it, but getting `The type or method has 1 generic parameter(s), but 2 generic argument(s) were provided. A generic argument must be provided for each generic parameter.` error.   StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.SanityCheckGenericArguments(RuntimeType[] genericArguments, RuntimeType[] genericParamters)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
       at Here_is_this_code(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Comment: When I commented `.MakeGenericMethod(...)` I got `Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.`.

Comment: It turned out that `funcType` was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

`TProperty` exists only in the C# source code text. The compiler always resolves it to a concrete type. If you have a method

```
void Test<T>(T arg)
{
}
```

and call it like this

```
Test("hello");
Test(3);
```

The compiler generates code for two methods!

```
void Test(string arg)
{
}

void Test(int arg)
{
}
```

This means that you have to supply concrete types for your generic parameters if you want to have an invokable method.

Answer (score 2):

Property expressions require the property access to be on a specific object. There's a few options you can take here. First, if this is being done within one of your entity objects, you can simple use a ConstantExpression to build the property expression:

```
// Already have PropertyInfo in propInfo
Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this, this.GetType()), propInfo)
```

However, since you need a `Expression<Func<TStructuralType, TProperty>>`, then it seems like you're going to have to build it using a ParameterExpression:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Parameter.Expression(typeof(MyEntity), "eParam");
Expression propExp = Expression.Property(pe, propInfo);
```

HOWEVER, here's the kicker... This is just a MemberExpression. To convert to the expression you need, you need to use `Expression.Lambda` to get a Func<> expression of the type you need. The problem? You don't know the type of the property to define the generic parameters of the lambda expression!

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, ????>> eFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, ????>>(propExp, pe);
```

This is the crux of the problem of doing it this way. That's not to say it can't be done... It's just that using this method IN THIS WAY isn't going to work. You'll have to use a bit runtime and static typing trickery (as well as judicious use of Actions instead of Funcs) to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This code will get you an `Expression<Func<>>` of the desired type. Note that there is an `Expression.Lambda(...)` override that doesn't need you to specify the type of the `Func` returned.

```
    var t = typeof(Foo);
    var pi = t.GetProperty(...);
    var prm = Expression.Parameter(t, t.Name);
    var prx = Expression.Property(prm, pi);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(prx, prm);
```

Note that in many cases you don't have to bother with creating the `Expression<Func<>>` this way, assuming `structureConfiguration` below is a `StructureConfiguration<Foo>`, type inference will allow you to write something like this:

```
    structureConfiguration.Ignore(f => f.Bar);
```