# How to build expressions for reflected properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, expression-trees

I've built an MVC Html helper with this signature:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString EditFieldFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object additionalViewData = null)
```

I'm trying to build another helper that will reflect on the properties of an object and then call EditFieldFor for each of the reflected properties. But as you can see, that method needs an expression.

How can I turn a PropertyInfo into an expression?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622620/64334) showed me what to do. Here's what I did:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in editFields)
{
    var expParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel)); // TModel is a generic parameter on this method
    var expProp = Expression.Property(expParam, propertyInfo);
    var expression = Expression.Lambda(expProp, expParam);

    var fieldHtml = (MvcHtmlString)typeof (HtmlHelpers)
        .GetMethod("EditFieldFor")
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TModel), propertyInfo.PropertyType)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] {html, expression, null});

    editFormHtml.Append(fieldHtml);
}
```

Comment: Thats a nice one to know, thats for posting the answer.