# Can I map a protected ICollection using EF6 code first mappings?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Given the class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    protected virtual ICollection<Role> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Role>(UserRoles.ToArray()); }
    }
}
```

How can I map the the UserRoles using EF6 code-first mappings? I don't want to expose any of the ICollection features outside of my entity. I also do not want to pollute my domain model with persistence information. I would like it to stay persistence agnostic. That means attributes are out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using reflection. Here is the gist of it:

```
internal class UserMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Users");
        HasKey(u => u.Id);
        Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("UserID");

        var userType = typeof (User);
        var propertyInfo = userType.GetProperty("UserRoles", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (User), "u");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
        var funcType = typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(userType, typeof (ICollection<Role>));// propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);

        ((ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<User, Role>)GetType().GetMethod("HasMany")
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Role))
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { lambda }))
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                m.ToTable("UserRoles");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Much love to @darkgray for this answer here:

[How to convert PropertyInfo to property expression and use it to invoke generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621736/how-to-convert-propertyinfo-to-property-expression-and-use-it-to-invoke-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this post](http://romiller.com/2013/01/23/ef6-code-first-mapping-all-private-properties-using-custom-conventions/) can help you - though it's EF 6 alpha, so I don't know if it's still applicable.

In essence, you can define a custom convention in your `OnModelCreating()` method that takes all non-public fields and includes them in your model (code fragment taken directly from linked page):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSets etc. defined here

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entities()
        .Configure(c =>
            {
                var nonPublicProperties = c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (var p in nonPublicProperties)
                {
                    c.Property(p).HasColumnName(p.Name);
                }
            });
      }
}
```