# FluentAPI mapping with POCO in EF4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, fluent

I'm learning EF4.1 against the northwind database. I have created a POCO class like this intentionally with non-identical column names and properties that don't exist in the scheme so I can learn mapping in preparation for updating my legacy app:

```
  public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public Decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
        public Int16 QuantityInStock { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to map my schema to this entity like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Map(config =>
        {
            config.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.ProductName,
                p.ProductID,
                p.CategoryID,
                p.Discontinued,
                p.UnitPrice
            });
        });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().ToTable("Products");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Strangely, when I try this:

```
Product tmp = db.Products.Find(4);
```

I get this exception and I can't tell why since  I'm referring to  and I even mapped it ToTable("Products"):
**`{"Invalid object name 'dbo.Product1'."}`**

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Map` you are using a quite advanced mapping option in Code-First called **Table Splitting**. Your mapping says that the properties of your entity `Product` you have listed in `Properties(p => new...)` should be mapped to another table than the rest of the properties. The rest of the properties is in table `Products` as you have defined in your `ToTable` call. For the other properties you don't have specified a table name at all (which should be `ToTable` within the `Map(config => config.ToTable(...) ...` action). My guess is that EF assumes some kind of default table name `Product1` which apparently doesn't exist.

I'm not sure if you really want to split your entity to two different tables. Reading your first sentences...

> ... non-identical column names and properties that don't exist in the
>   scheme ...

... I think you need mainly the following two mapping options:

Properties in the model class without corresponding columns in the database are not mapped properties:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(p => p.QuantityInStock);
```

With data annotations:

```
[NotMapped]
public Int16 QuantityInStock { get; set; }
```

And you can map a property name to another column name by:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.Discontinued)
    .HasColumnName("MyOtherColumnName");
```

With data annotations:

```
[Column("MyOtherColumnName")]
public bool Discontinued { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this Ignore option but then every time I add a property to my class I'd have to update the map to ignore it which is a pain. Worse I have existing business classes that I want to use that have lots of properties and would be a pain to ignore each one. Is there any way to specify which properties should be set rather than which to ignore?

Comment: @powlette: No, not that I am aware of.

Comment: This was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585263/use-entity-frameworks-structuraltypeconfiguration-ignore-to-ignore-all-proper